# Smart search indexing not working

Tags: search, joomla, joomla3.2

I want to start using joomlas smart search plugin.

The "content - smart search plugin" is enabled. All the other plugins that have to do with search are also enabled.

When I go on components -> smart search, I see that no content has been indexed. When I click on the index button a small pop-up appears, however, it stays blank, no text, no nothing in it, just the close 'x'.

Any ideas?

I am using Joomla! 3.2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really a question about programming, but anywho.

If you seeing a blank screen, this probably means that you've encountered either:

1. a permissions error of some kind that results in a browser timeout or
2. a Javascript error.
3. a server side error permissions or PHP

First, check your browser Javascript console for errors.
Second, turn on Error reporting and Debug mode in Joomla and repeat steps looking for error messages.
Third, check server and `PHP` error logs for clues.

The modal overlay for the "Smart Search Indexer" is an `iframe` that loads and then runs several AJAX requests.

Model open the `iframe` at:

```
index.php?option=com_finder&view=indexer&tmpl=component
```

If the `iframe`'s initial URL works you should at least see something like this:

[image: Joomla Smart Search Index "starting"]

If you're not seeing any of that UI look for timeouts in your browsers web inspector, you may see that the resource i.e. the URL above didn't load. In that case check your servers logs and any php error logs.

After that loads, AJAX requests are sent to:
    index.php?option=com_finder&tmpl=component&format=json&ALONGNUMBER=1

with various tasks:

- `&task=indexer.start`
- `&task=indexer.batch`
- `&task=indexer.optimize`

Based on what you've said though, you're not gettig to the AJAX calls yet.

#### Update

Based on the the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'addEvent' and a warning
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
```

You have a Javascript conflict going on — I would look at disabling any 3rd part extensions that use Javascript as one of them may be loading conflicting `JQuery`/`Mootools`/`Bootstrap` code.

If you have new content regularly being added, now that the initial index has been run, you can setup a `CRON` job to run the Smart Search CLI periodically.

Comment: there is one error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'addEvent'` and a warning `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`
Not sure if any of these have to do with the matter. The link you provided opened another window and indexed everything, no problem.

Comment: OK, that sounds like a JS conflict, see the updated answer. :D